# dynamically increase the height of UITableViewCell while editing (individual cell)

Tags: uitableview, swift2

how can we increase the size of row (cell) while editing, same as when we add new contact (the text field's height  increases as we enter more text) [![field into contact][1]][1]

ignore the label in this pic[image]

am talking about a single cell , i've seen many question to related with this but none of them was in swift and my primary language is swift so i was not able to figure out with how to deal with this but i tried this :-

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
```

but its not working while editing then i tried to get the size of content in my textView which is inside my tableView cell and resize the tableView cell according to textView's content size with this :-

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {



    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;



    return txtViewDescription.contentSize.width
}
```

but its increasing the size of all the cells and not doing anything while editing the textview , i know what am trying is not the proper approach for it , if anybody knows how can i deal with this then please guide me it will very helpful for me :)  and if my question is not clear enough than please let me know i'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path.

You don't need to set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` and `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;` all the time - you can just do these once on initial setup (maybe `viewDidLoad`.

What you need to do is something like the below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

  if indexPath == indexPathOfCellBeingEdited {
    txtViewDescription.contentSize.width
  } else {
    return 44
  }

}
```

Essentially this function will be called once for every row so you need to see which row you are on before deciding whether to return the default height of the calculated height.

In order to force the tableView to recalculate the height of the rows you may need to call

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```